# Is it possible to reset sealed deck slots?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

In Magic 2014, you are given two slots for sealed deck play. Each slot corresponds to the random card selection you get when you first use the slot, and there doesn't seem to be a way to delete or free up this slot so you can generate another random set of cards.

Is it possible, through out-of-game means, to reset your sealed deck slots? Like deleting and redownloading the game, deleting the saved game somehow if it exists, etc.

Comment: This is really frustrating me too. I bought this game solely because of the new sealed deck mode. I thought it'd be useful for practice at building decks. It's ridiculous that you're only allowed to play the game mode twice, before needing to spend money each time after. It feels like they're trying to milk money from you.  It wouldn't be so bad If the cards had some intrinsic value such as carrying over to future games or being available outside the sealed format. In reality it's just money down the drain. It's just disappointing and a very cynical money grab in my view.

Comment: I've decided to write a letter / email to wizards to let them know how I feel. I suggest that anyone else who feels aggrieved by this do the same. If they don't have our feedback they won't know that anything is wrong. Hopefully if enough people voice their frustrations they'll do something about it. I'd personally be happy to pay an extra £5 to unlock unlimited sealed deck, but £1 a go just isn't anywhere near worth it.

Comment: @DoctorJones Having played it, I can see what they were aiming for. If you want the true "Sealed Deck" experience, this is what it is.

You get duff boosters, you live with duff boosters, this is in fact the wages of boosters.

But I agree that the way it's been done feels more like a cash grab than additional unlockable decks (even though it's the same core principle, as it's unlocking additional decks).

I really enjoyed Sealed, and the lack of a reset gave each booster tension. But I totally get your view.

Personally, more annoyed that there were no 2-faced cards. Lycanthropes Represent!

Comment: @deworde - That is poor! If they had any value outside the game, I completely agree... but, it is a game that you purchase and the cards have no value outside the game... It really can't be anything other than a greedy cash grab on fans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the card pool that's tied to a particular slot somehow incorporates the account name in the seed for the randomization function the game uses for creating your sealed pool, if you're playing on a platform that allows you to change your username, it may be possible to delete the sealed deck data on your platform, change your username, and open new boosters in that slot.

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/MagicDotP/comments/1h9agm/is_there_a_way_to_delete_a_sealed_deck_completely/

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I have it on PS3, the only way I've found to make a new sealed deck for free is to go into the save data utility in the game tab and delete the "magic" save file.  Downside, this will also delete your campaign and player stats, but it will open up the chance for more sealed draws for free.

Answer (score 1):

The sealed cards are attached to your account. No amount of deleting will change your cards, you will always get the same ones. They made it this way so you would need to buy more slots if you are unhappy with your two decks.

Believe me, I already tried.

Comment: Do you mean the GameCenter account? So if you use a different GameCenter account, you'll have free slots again?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the application info screen and clean it. Then use another character name.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid you have to delete your sealed deck save, or your game's sealed play will remain messed up.